# thread not working for function with template arguments

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I am trying to implement multithreaded merge sort, but my attempt is fails to compile. Here is my code :

```
template <class RandomAccessIterator>
void merge_sort (RandomAccessIterator begin,RandomAccessIterator end)
{
    int N = end - begin;
    int N1,N2;

    if (N == 1)
        return;

    RandomAccessIterator mid = begin + (end-begin)/2;


    // merge_sort (begin,mid); // this is OK
    // merge_sort (mid,end);   // this is OK

    thread t1 (merge_sort,begin,mid); // error
    thread t2 (merge_sort,mid,end);   // error

    t1.join ();
    t2.join ();

    N1 = mid - begin;
    N2 = end - mid;

    merge (begin,N1,mid,N2);
}
```

Errors Messages from gcc (`g++ -std=c++11 merge-multithread.cpp`):

```
merge-multithread.cpp: In instantiation of ‘void merge_sort(RandomAccessIterator, RandomAccessIterator) [with RandomAccessIterator = int*]’:
merge-multithread.cpp:76:25:   required from here
merge-multithread.cpp:60:33: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::thread::thread(<unresolved overloaded function type>, int*&, int*&)’
  thread t1 (merge_sort,begin,mid);
                                 ^
In file included from merge-multithread.cpp:4:0:
/usr/include/c++/5.2.0/thread:133:7: note: candidate: template<class _Callable, class ... _Args> std::thread::thread(_Callable&&, _Args&& ...)
       thread(_Callable&& __f, _Args&&... __args)
       ^
/usr/include/c++/5.2.0/thread:133:7: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
merge-multithread.cpp:60:33: note:   couldn't deduce template parameter ‘_Callable’
  thread t1 (merge_sort,begin,mid);
                                 ^
In file included from merge-multithread.cpp:4:0:
/usr/include/c++/5.2.0/thread:128:5: note: candidate: std::thread::thread(std::thread&&)
     thread(thread&& __t) noexcept
     ^
/usr/include/c++/5.2.0/thread:128:5: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 3 provided
/usr/include/c++/5.2.0/thread:122:5: note: candidate: std::thread::thread()
     thread() noexcept = default;
```

Comment: I'd be curious what your performance increase on this is. First, it might be better to have it handle when there are less than a few elements in the list as a special case (sorting say... 4 elements with bubble sort is probably faster than the overhead of creating an additional 2 threads with 3 calls to merge). But it's also curious because as you need to merge larger and larger arrays, you are doing it with less threads. (For instance your last merge, the largest, will be single threaded).

Comment: The key part of the compile error is "`<unresolved overloaded function type>`". Good pattern to commit to memory.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`merge_sort` itself is a function template; to get the address of one of the instantiated functions you need to specify all template arguments:

```
thread t1 (&merge_sort<RandomAccessIterator>,begin,mid);
//         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
```

or use a static cast:

```
thread t1 (static_cast<void(*)(RandomAccessIterator,RandomAccessIterator)>(&merge_sort),begin,mid);
```

...or use a lambda expression and let the compiler automatically deduce the types of arguments:

```
thread t1 ([begin,mid]{merge_sort(begin, mid);});
```

Comment: I'd order them 231 myself.